# Font requirement with large Spacing

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I am currently using custom spacing for a design that I am working on. But further discussion with an app developer, I was told that custom font spacing would not be possible. I just want to confirm if there are fonts similar to the Lobster font, with a default spacing larger than Lobster.

Many thanks in advance,
Mayank

Comment: Hi Mayanks sagar, welcome to GDSE. I am sorry, but it's unclear to me what you're trying to ask. What do you mean with 'large kerning'? You can set the kerning and / or tracking of any typeface the way you want in most common image processors. Besides, what have you found that didn't fit your goals, and why? Showing a bit of effort increases you chance for a good answer a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vincent. Thanks for the reply and apologies for the type error. What I meant was font spacing!I am currently using custom spacing for a design that I am working on. But further discussion with an app developer, I was told that custom font spacing would not be possible. I just want to confirm if there are fonts similar to the Lobster font, with a default spacing larger than Lobster. Also, is there a way a custom font spacing can be implemented from the development point of view.

Comment: If you could point me to an article about the same, it would be really awesome!

Thanks,

Comment: I personally have no clue, but if you'd add the info from that comment into the actual question, you might get some answers. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proper typographic terminology will help us understand what you are asking here.

Tracking, the space between all characters, [can be manipulated with CSS using the letter-spacing property.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/) This has wide browser compatibility and shouldn't be an issue at all.

Kerning, the space between two characters such as within a logo, is not manipulable with CSS. CSS can only act on discrete elements in the DOM.

However, if you are ok with adding some cruft markup it is possible to do something like this:

```
<p class="company-name">Kern Me Please</p>
```

Insert a few spans, enclosing the kerning pairs:

```
<p class="company-name">K<span class="kern-er">er</span>n Me P<span class="le">le</span>ase</p>
```

And use the letter-spacing property to style those spans.